# Как убрать обводку у input?

Tags: html, css, input

У кнопки `<input type="submit">` после натягивания всех стилей, появилась странная внутренняя обводка. Не нашел в инспекторе элементов, что придаёт элементу эту обводку. Как убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<input class="form-submit-button" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
```

```
.form-submit-button {
  height: 54px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 21.7636px;
  line-height: 26px;
  letter-spacing: -0.0024em;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #4d30ff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.form-submit-button {
  height: 54px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 21.7636px;
  line-height: 26px;
  letter-spacing: -0.0024em;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #4d30ff;
  border-radius: 2px;


  border:none; /*Добавь это*/
}
```

Comment: Нет, не помогло

Comment: Извини ошибся, вместо outline: none; напиши border: none;

Comment: Теперь да, то что надо.